# Powershell Email Notification File Created

Tags: powershell, email, temp

I have written a code for PowerShell to notify me when a new file has been added to a designated folder, but every time the file is opened it creates a temp file and I keep getting those emails each time I open it. I have tried to create an if-else statement so that the temp file emails go to a different email address. Ideally, I would like to not receive those emails at all. If any of you know of a way that this is possible please help me. I have copied my code below.

```
$folder = "File Folder Path"
$mailserver = "mailserver"
$recipient = "Recipient@Email.com"

$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder -Property @{
   IncludeSubdirectories = $true
   EnableRaisingEvents=$true
}


$created = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier CreatedEvent -Action {
   $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
   $s = New-Object System.Security.SecureString
   $anon = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON", $s)
   If ($fsw -ccontains '~') {
      Send-MailMessage -To "MyEmail@Email.com" `
                    -From "Email@Email.com" `
                    -Subject “File Creation Event” `
                    -Body "A file was created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)" `
                    -SmtpServer $mailserver `
                    -Credential $anon
    }
   Else {
      Send-MailMessage -To $recipient `
                    -From "Email@Email.com" `
                    -Subject “File Creation Event” `
                    -Body "A file was created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)" `
                    -SmtpServer $mailserver `
                    -Credential $anon
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer has resolved your issue, consider accepting it - see [what to do when someone answers help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It kinda helps the site work. I've also noticed you took the `*` when using my solution in follow up questions - it's important for like matches as otherwise it looks for file that are literally called `~`.

Answer (score 3):

Contains works on an array, not a string. Use `-like` or `-match`.

If you don't want an e-mail, don't write the code to send one.

For example, this only send an e-mail if your temp file does not contain `~`. As there is no else, no action is taken if the file name *does* contain `~`.

```
If ($fsw -notlike '*~*') {
  Send-MailMessage -To $recipient `
                -From "Email@Email.com" `
                -Subject “File Creation Event” `
                -Body "A file was created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)" `
                -SmtpServer $mailserver `
                -Credential $anon
}
```